# Boltzmann molecule motion

Tags: thermodynamics

Boltzmann stipulates that molecules in a hot state (for example air molecules) move towards molecules in a cold state because they have a much higher probability of doing so. (Corrections on this statement welcome.)

But doesn't this mean that given enough trials, in rare instances SOME cold molecules should at some point move toward hot molecules? Is it possible for the number of these molecules to reach a point where the effect is measurable?  Of course, this never happens.  Have I misunderstood Boltzmann?

Comment: I think you got it right. It's like asking: Given enough time, could a macroscopic thing (like a ball for e..g.) be found on the other side of the wall due to the tunnel effect? The anser is yes, but the probability of this happening is terribly small.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question you are interested in. As the diffusion of a gas is a random process, your statement about the probability is not clear.